# Stripe API Update Customer Credit Card Details - Java

Tags: java, stripe-payments

Cannot figure out for the life of me how to do this. I've tested the following which isn't working;

```
String stripeCustomerID = "123";
Customer cu = Customer.retrieve(stripeCustomerID);
cu.setDefaultSource(token);
Map<String, Object> updateParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
updateParams.put("default_source", token);
enter code here`cu.update(updateParams);
```

This is the only place the Stripe API documentation hasn't had the answer.

Has anyone implemented this previously?

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer thanks to Matthew;

```
Customer cu = Customer.retrieve(stripeCustomerID);
Map<String, Object> updateParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
updateParams.put("source", token);
cu.update(updateParams);
```

Comment: cu.update(updateParams); // Update method is not found in Customer.

Answer (score 4):

`default_source` is expecting a card id not a token id. Thus you either need to:

1) Add the card to the customer and then update the `default_source` property
or
2) You can set the `source` property of the customer to the token. By setting `source` you will add the new card, delete the old default_source, and then set the new one as the default, all in the same API call.

Comment: Option 2 sounds best as it does everything at once. There is no 'source' property on the customer though, there is only 'sources' which is an ExternalAccountCollection, which I'd imagine is essentially a list of all cards. I've checked to see if it is possible to add a token to either of these and I can't spot anything? Just sending a token would be ideal.

Comment: Source is available via the customer.update method. https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer-source

Comment: Perfect, thanks Matthew. Working now. I was using the "default_source" previously instead of the "source".